# Button for the appearance of the SideBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sidebar

At the moment, I have the following structure on the site: SideBar (located on the left) and the main part of the site. I made it so that when the browser width is reduced, the Sidebar is hidden, leaving only the main part of the site (the code is presented below). And further, the SideBar appears only when the browser is expanded. It works.

But I'd like to add the following: When the browser is in a minimized state, add a button that, when clicked, will overlay the SideBar on the main menu (thus leaving the main body of the site behind).

For a demonstration, I will present https://catalog.onliner.by/tv (make the browser width minimal and click the "Фильтры" button)

And accordingly I would like to make a button to close the SideBar

I would be very grateful for any advice

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-einstein-mh1xyo

WindowSize.jsx

```
export default function WindowSize () {
   const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
        width: undefined,
        height: undefined
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            function handleResize() {
                setWindowSize({
                    width: window.innerWidth,
                    height: window.innerHeight
                });
            }
            window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
            handleResize();
            return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        }
    }, []); 
    return windowSize;
};
```

App.jsx

```
    return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <AppContext.Provider
                value={{ filters, setFilters}}>
                <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                {size.width > 600 && <Sidebar />}
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path='/devices/' element={<PockId />} />
                        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/devices" replace />} />
                    </Routes>
                </div>
            </AppContext.Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
);
```

Once again, my expectations: when the SideBar disappears, that a button would appear with which you can open the SideBar, leaving the main page behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a state for show and hide the sidebar by toggling a class which makes a `translate` animation to the sidebar.

Ex of the state.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const [hideSidebar, setHideSidebar] = useState(false)
```

You can give your sidebar a class for example `sidebar-left-nav`

```
.sidebar-left-nav {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0px, 0px);
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.closed.sidebar-left-nav {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Then by your `hideSidebar` state, you can toggle the `closed` class when the button is clicked.

```
<button onClick={() => { setHideSidebar(prev => !prev)})>Toggle Sidebar</div>
```

In the sidebar container

```
className={`sidebar-left-nav ${hideSidebar && 'closed'}`}
```

Please check this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-hodgkin-lf7qwt

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Only I did not quite understand where I should add these lines of code. I can provide additional code for a complete answer

Comment: Yes, please provide a working example of your code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-einstein-mh1xyo

Comment: I just update the answer with the solution in codesanxbox, please check.

Comment: Yes thank you. This is something similar to what I meant. But is it possible to make the "Toggle Sidebar" button appear only when the Sidebar disappears when the screen is compressed?

Comment: Is it what you are looking for?
https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-sunset-d54ex4

Comment: Sorry, maybe we misunderstood each other: Now when you click on the "Toggle Sidebar" button, it disappears. But I would like it to remain and the user can close the sidebar if desired.

Comment: I provided a link to the desired result in the condition. Perhaps this will make it easier to understand

Comment: `Sorry, maybe we misunderstood each other: Now when you click on the "Toggle Sidebar" button, it disappears. But I would like it to remain and the user can close the sidebar if desired. `

This result was already achieved in the previous code I mentioned.

Comment: `I provided a link to the desired result in the condition. Perhaps this will make it easier to understand`, this link https://catalog.onliner.by/tv you mentioned in the question is not accessible.

Comment: Anyway, I provide you with the concepts and the solution for the main issue, and you can use my code and manipulate it to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I marked your answer. But I would like the Toggle Sidebar button to not disappear when you click on it, but only disappear when the screen is resized

Comment: You are welcome, Is that what you are looking for? https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-snow-dcbktx

Comment: Perfectly! You are great programmer and good person!